# What is the name of this surreal/minimalist style?

Tags: style-identification, minimalistic

[image: Simple Design Aesthetic]

I want to study some tutorials on in this style and would like to know exactly what it's called.

Answer (score 3):

### Minimal Flat Landscapes

Some examples:

**Henrique Folster**, https://folster.me/

[image: Folster]

**Malika Favre**, http://malikafavre.com/

[image: Malika Favre]

**Thomas Danthony**, https://www.handsomefrank.com/illustrators/thomas-danthony

[image]

Comment: I was looking at a lot of Henrique Folster. His work is so simple and lovely. So, you would just call it "minimal flat landscape"? Thank you!

Comment: @CrystalH Lately the names of computer graphic styles are given by the largest number of matches you find in Google. If you type **Flat Landscape** is more oriented to **Flat Design**. The word **Minimal** is the one that put the difference.