# What is this style called? And any tips on making this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

[image: What is this style?]

I recently saw this image and I wondered what the style is, and how I would go about making it.

Comment: You already have got a wide answer about the style. Technically there's boxy forms (=only rare curves), gradient fills, glow effects and stepped blendings. Those light beams which fade are gradients with transparency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Retro Wave

There is a musical style which reinterprets the 80s: [Synthwave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthwave) or Retro wave. In design, it takes on the aesthetics of that decade in an exaggerated way, based on the the late 70's [Cyberpunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberpunk) and [New Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_wave_music), using and digitally adapting the representation techniques from those years: airbrush, masking, fluorescent inks, perspective, orthogonal grids, blur, motion blur, and inspired by album covers, movie posters or Arcade games (Thron). You can adjust the search looking for [Retro Wave Skyline](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=FTldXJHBJ4ajUOONitAI&q=retrowave%20skyline&oq=retrowave%20skyline&gs_l=img.3..0i19.21808.24764..25259...0.0..0.243.1014.9j1j1......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i7i30j0i67j0j0i8i7i30.-4KVXJF1P1Y)

[image: Retro Wave Skyline]
<sub>Source [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uhqZojhku4)</sub>

---

Also [Flat 2.0 design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/114857/120647), adjusting the search within this style by adding **neon**: *flat neon design* or *flat neon skyline*.

[image: Neon Skyline]

<sub>Source [freepik.com](https://de.freepik.com/vektoren-kostenlos/flacher-neonstadtbild-hintergrund_3454262.htm)</sub>

[image: Behance]

<sub>Source [Behance](https://www.behance.net/gallery/22721859/Virgin-Atlantic-2015)</sub>

---

**Related question**
[What is the name of this surreal/minimalist style?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/112957/120647)

Comment: Would you be aware of any tutorials on the style? Thanks any ways :)